# Hide/clear input field with prototype

Tags: javascript, forms, label, prototypejs, hide

I have the following script:

```
if (Object.isUndefined(Axent)) { var Axent = { } }
 Axent.SelfLabeledInput = Class.create({
initialize: function() {
    var labelSelector = arguments[0] || 'label';
    $$(labelSelector).findAll(function(l) {return (l.readAttribute('for') !== null)}).each(function(l){
        l.hide();
        $(l.readAttribute('for'))._value = l.innerHTML;
        if ($(l.readAttribute('for')).value.empty()) {
            $(l.readAttribute('for')).value = $(l.readAttribute('for'))._value
        }
        $(l.readAttribute('for')).observe('blur',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == '') Event.element(e).value = Event.element(e)._value;});
        $(l.readAttribute('for')).observe('focus',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == Event.element(e)._value) Event.element(e).value = '';});
    });
}
});
```

And the following form :

```
    <form name="comform" action="#" method="post" id="commentform">
    <div class="input"> 
<p>
<label for="comment">Type your comment here...</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="8" cols="10" class="" ></textarea>
</p>
</div>
    <div class="input">
<p>
<label for="author">Name (required)</label>        
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" size="22" class=""/>
</p>
</div>
    <div class="input">
<p>
<label for="email">Email (gravatar enabled) (required)</label>         
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="22" class=""/>
</p>
</div>
    <div class="input">
<p>
<label for="url">Website (optional)</label>        
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" size="22" />
</p>
</div>
    <div class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="Leave comment" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" id="hidden" value=""> 
</div>

</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
new Axent.SelfLabeledInput('#commentform label');
//]]>
</script>
```

I want to write a function from this script such that when I press the submit on this form, and an input field is focused, it hides/clears it, so it doesn't get submitted to the database.

This works with the latest Prototype lib. I don't know any JavaScript, so I need your help. I'm using this form for my WordPress comments area.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work! Here's the final code if someone else wants to run it:

```
if (Object.isUndefined(Axent)) { var Axent = { } }
Axent.SelfLabeledInput = Class.create({
initialize: function() {
    var labelSelector = arguments[0] || 'label';
    $$(labelSelector).findAll(function(l) {return (l.readAttribute('for') !== null)}).each(function(l){
            l.hide();
            var el = $(l.readAttribute('for'));
            el._value = l.innerHTML;
            if (el.value.empty()) {
                    el.value = el._value
            }
            el.observe('blur',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == '') Event.element(e).value = Event.element(e)._value;});
            el.observe('focus',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == Event.element(e)._value) Event.element(e).value = '';});
    $(el.form).observe( 'submit', (function(thisel) { return function(e) {
            if( thisel.value == thisel._value ) { thisel.value = '' }
    }})(el));
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry, labels won't get submitted.

This script will remove the labels from the DOM on submit tho. It has to be run after the DOM is loaded (well, at least the form) **and if your form elements are inside the labels they will disappear too!**

```
document.getElementById( 'commentform' ).onsubmit = function() {
    var labels = this.getElementsByTagName( 'label' );
    while( labels[0] ) {
        labels[0].parentNode.removeChild( labels[0] );
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is not a prototype script. It's **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript.

Answer (score 0):

The elements are pre-filled with the label text. On focus the default text disappears and reappears on blur if the element is still empty.

You could try this. I don't use prototype, so it's a guess in places.

```
if (Object.isUndefined(Axent)) { var Axent = { } }
Axent.SelfLabeledInput = Class.create({
initialize: function() {
    var labelSelector = arguments[0] || 'label';
    $$(labelSelector).findAll(function(l) {return (l.readAttribute('for') !== null)}).each(function(l){
        l.hide();
        var el = $(l.readAttribute('for'));
        el._value = l.innerHTML;
        if (el.value.empty()) {
            el.value = el._value
        }
        el.observe('blur',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == '') Event.element(e).value = Event.element(e)._value;});
        el.observe('focus',function(e){if(Event.element(e).value == Event.element(e)._value) Event.element(e).value = '';});
        $(el.form).observe( 'submit', (function(thisel) { return function(e) {
            if( thisel.value == thisel._value ) { thisel.value = '' }
        }})(el));
    });
}
```